# PHP: Adding entries from php to json

Tags: php, json

I have no knowledge of php, but from an iOS app I am trying to pass variables to json which can be accessible later, each time user complete level the post method push 3 variables and its value which adds that info into file like this

php code:

```
<?php
header ('Location: ');
$handle = fopen("data.json", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, ":");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

and I get the output like this after two users used post method:

```
Name:user1
Points:100
Level:1

Name:user2
Points:200
Level:2
```

can someone please help me to get json format output, with every time user push data with the post method it adds info to existing data instead of overwriting it?

I want output like this:

```
[ 
{"Name":"user1","Score":"100","Level":"1"},{"Name":"user2","Score":"200","Level":"2"}
]
```

Comment: You can use `$jsonString = json_encode($_POST)` which will encode the associative array that POST is getting into a JSON string. But it sounds like you need CRUD persistent storage solution. I think Firebase or something like it may fit your needs better. I'm pretty sure Firebase has a direct API for iOS that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
$json[] = json_encode($_POST);
file_put_contents("data.json", $json);
```

This decodes the current JSON file, then appends the new information and then saves over the existing JSON file.

Comment: Should I add it like this?

`<?php
header ('Location: ');
$handle = fopen("data.json", "a");

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
$json[] = json_encode($_POST);
file_put_contents("data.json", $json)

foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, ":");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>`

Comment: You don't need `$handle`, `fopen()`, `foreach()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`.